# Get json results in NSuserDefault and display result for annotation in MapKit in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, mapkit

I want to get result from json and save this result in NSUserDefault, after I want to use the json array saved in NSUserDefault to add multiple annotation on the MapKit. 
Currently to get json result, I use this : ( Swift 2.x )

```
         let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    //Get user content//
   let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.example.com/folder/coordonate.php")
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)

    // modify the request as necessary, if necessary

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        if data == nil {
            print("request failed \(error)")
            return
        }

        do {
            if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
                print(json)
                // print : {tab = "[london,paris]";}


                var test = json["tab"]

                defaults.setObject(test, forKey: "annotation") as? NSArray



                         }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

And to get the NSUserdefault in another view, I try this code :

```
  let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    let test = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("annotation") as! NSArray
    map.addAnnotations(test as! [MKAnnotation])
    print("We saved this data: \(test)")
    //No print, error before
```

But I have an error when I try with this method.

```
Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x1971a3958) to 'NSArray' (0x1971a4308).
```

Comment: I guess that json["tab"] is a string and not an array

Comment: It's in the php script where I need to edit the code ?

Comment: can you please do `print(test)` and add it to your question?

Comment: I have edit my question with the result

Comment: i'm afraid that it's a string and not an NSArray, it could happen if your json is invalid. because "[london,paris]"; doesn't look like NSDIctionary member in print

Comment: This is my php code : `<?php
$results = Array("tab" => "[london,paris]");

header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo json_encode($results);

?>` How to resolve the problem , maybe changing all the code ?

Answer (score 0):

If the "tab" property JSON actually being returned is:

> [london, paris]

Then the property is not an array. What you're looking for would be:

> ['london', 'paris']

But additionally I can tell you that even if the "tab" property is a properly formatted JSON array your code will fail when it attempts to convert it to [MKAnnotation] anyway.  That's because iOS's JSON library does not know how to convert a generic NSArray into it's typed equivalent.  The [NSJSONSerialization documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/) indicates all the types that JSON will convert to.  Best case scenario the "tab" property is an array of items with the same structure as MKAnnotation and are being converted to an array of dictionaries that you will have to convert to MKAnnotation yourself.  But the JSON provided currently evaluates as a string.  With my suggested change it will instead evaluate to an array of strings- still not sufficient to create an MKAnnotation from.

Comment: I see, but I don't knwo how to process ?

Comment: I assume the array of strings is supposed to represent the annotation's title?  In that case you would create an MKAnnotation instance for each string in the array and assign the string as the title.

Comment: And can I do this in a same array ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  There's quite a few steps you're missing.  You first need a class that actually adheres to the MKAnnotation protocol by at least exposing a 'coordinate' property.  Then you must use the array of information you've stored in NSUserDefaults to create instances of your MKAnnotation class and then assign them to the MapView.

Answer (score 0):

change your php code to

```
$results = Array("tab" => ["london","paris"]);
```

instead of

```
$results = Array("tab" => "[london,paris]");
```

p.s
if using php earlier than 5.5 (or 5.4 not quite remember) then use:

```
$results = Array("tab" => Array("london","paris"));
```

==========================

you are casting the `setObject` func to `NSArray` **and not the test object**

```
defaults.setObject(test, forKey: "annotation") as? NSArray
```

should be

```
if let arrayTest = test as? NSArray{
     defaults.setObject(arrayTest, forKey: "annotation")
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks but now I have this error : `[8158:591496] -[__NSCFString coordinate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x174223dc0
2015-12-01 20:39:46.229 Blabla[8158:591496] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString coordinate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x174223dc0'`

Comment: When I try to access to map view controller but Xcode says it's in AppDelegate where is the error ( where is the code to get the array from json )

Comment: who said you can cast the test to [MKAnnotation]?

Comment: True, so I have commented the MKAnnotation, and the print is : `We saved this data: (
    london,
    paris
)`

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON data has to be one of the valid NSUserDefault types (String, NSArray, NSDictionary, NSData).

The quickest fix would be to store the JSON in NSUserDefaults as the NSData that comes back from the server.  Then deserialize the NSData on the reading of NSUserDefaults.

If storing a subset of the JSON from the server is really needed, I would use Dictionaries, Arrays and validate the data before storing it.  As a general Swift rule, I avoid using NSDictionary and NSArray to ensure the types are what I expect and won't cause a runtime crash.